# Implementing an interface with partial delegation

Tags: delphi, interface

I have a subobject who implements only a part of an interface:

```
  IMyTest = interface
    procedure P1;
    procedure P2;
  end;

  TMyTestP2Impl = class
    procedure P2;
  end;

  TMyTest = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IMyTest)
  private
    FMyTestP2Impl : TMyTestP2Impl;
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor  Destroy(); override;
    procedure P1;
    procedure P2;
  end;
```

So I have to write `TMyTest.P2` as follows:

```
procedure TMyTest.P2;
begin
  FMyTestP2Impl.P2();
end;
```

I'm wondering if there is a valid syntax for mapping `TMyTest.P2` to `FMyTestP2Impl.P2` without writing the implementation for `TMyTest.P2`. I mean something like the following:

```
  TMyTest = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IMyTest)
  private
    FMyTestP2Impl : TMyTestP2Impl;
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor  Destroy(); override;
    procedure P1;
    procedure P2 = FMyTestP2Impl.P2;
  end;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use [delegation to a class type property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Delegating_to_a_Class-Type_Property):

```
type
  IMyTest = interface
    procedure P1;
    procedure P2;
  end;

  TMyTestP2Impl = class
    procedure P2;
  end;

  TMyTest = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IMyTest)
  private
    FMyTestP2Impl: TMyTestP2Impl;
    property MyTestP2Impl: TMyTestP2Impl read FMyTestP2Impl implements IMyTest;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure P1;
  end;
```

Comment: Does it really work?  TMyTestP2Impl does not implements IMyTest, it only implements IMyTest.P2.

Comment: @KenBourassa, yes it works. That's the magic of Delphi...

Comment: OMG I never knew you could do this!

Comment: `They were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn't stop to think if they should`. Looks to me a lot like the kind of recipe for name collision that WITH is shuned for.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A rare moment - there should be a badge for that ;)

Comment: @KenBourassa per the documentation Stefan linked to: "*If the delegate property is of a **class type**, that class and its ancestors are searched for methods implementing the specified interface **before the enclosing class and its ancestors are searched**. Thus **it is possible to implement some methods in the class specified by the property, and others in the class where the property is declared**.*" That is why `P2()` can be implemented in another class, and that class doesn't have to implement `IMyTest` itself.

Comment: I'm using this technique for years and it allows for some neat constructs. Never had any problems.